# Links from the Homepage to the other pages don't work

Tags: wordpress

I have experience in designing/developing websites (static/dynamic). But new to wordpress :(. Recently I have created a CSS/XHTML website for a client who wanted it to be lunched using wordpress. I've converted the CSS/XHTML into a wordpress theme as I thought it might be easier than customizing another theme to fit my CSS/XHTML structure. Everything worked well locally. But when I uploaded files into the server (Styles, footer works fine.) homepage opens up fine. But when I click on the link to "about.php" page it doesn't work.

Initially all the links were loading the home page. Then I searched and changed the permalink structure to default and the "about.php" link gave 404 error. Then I replaced the "about.php" link into `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/about.php` as it was adviced in another article. Then it just opens up a blank page.

After struggling for a whole day, still stuck in the links issue. Hope any of you experts could save me. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the /about.php exactly is located ? In the rood directory of the WordPress ?

Comment: It is under the theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in wrong way. You have to see the template hierarchy first and then you have to go throught the wordpress administration panel and create your own menus